# appengine django dynamic table that is possibly empty

Tags: django, google-app-engine, customization

I have some code which pulls a list of items out of the datastore.

They look about like this:

```
class List(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

class Item(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  completed = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
```

In the Django template, I would like to conditionally display a table header only if there is at least one list element to show.  I'm astonished at how difficult this is.

For example:

```
{% for list in lists %}
   <font size="+2"><b>{{ list.name }}</b></font><br>
   <table><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>item</th><th>created</th><th>completed</th></tr>
   {% for item in list.items %}
      {% ifnotequal item.completed None %}
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>{{ item.name }} </td><td>{{ item.created }} </td><td>{{ item.completed }} </td></tr>
      {% endifnotequal %}
   {% endfor %}
   </table>
{%endfor%}
```

If I don't have any items in the list that meet the condition, I wind up with a sort of ugly empty table, like this:

```
**todo**
item    completed   delete
```

I would like to do something like, set a variable in Django like

```
{% set first = 1 %}
```

and then when I'm about to output at least one item for the table, do something like

```
   {% for item in list.items %}
      {% ifnotequal item.completed None %}
         {% if first %}
           <table><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>item</th><th>created</th><th>completed</th></tr>
           {% set first = 0 %}
         {% endif %}
       .... do the rest of the stuff
       {% endifnotequal %}
```

So, I went down the rabbithole of trying to create a custom tag for Django that will play nice within appengine as described here:

[one solution](http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/set-variable-django-template#comment-3817)

[another solution](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/using-custom-django-template-helpers.html)

and ran into so many errors, even tried the advice on these pages:

[another person with a similar problem](http://www.hipatic.com/2012/11/appengine-python-27-django-custom.html)

Not getting anywhere with this.  I'm using Python 2.7.  This shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any custom template tags here.

```
{% for list in lists %}
   {% for item in list.items %}
       {% if forloop.first %}     
           <font size="+2"><b>{{ list.name }}</b></font><br>
           <table><tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>item</th><th>created</th><th>completed</th></tr>
```

etc.

All this does is move the header into the inner for loop, and output it on the first iteration only. If the list is empty, it'll never enter that inner loop, and never output the header.

Comment: Yes, I would have done that except the list has a mixture of items, some of which are shown and some which are not.  So, it isn't necessarily the first item in the list that will be shown.  And it's possible that the list could have a number of items, but none of them are actually shown.  So I need something with a finer control than that